# Как включить слой парковок в js api яндекс.карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Вот пример отображения [парковок](https://yandex.ru/maps/2/saint-petersburg/?l=carparks), но в документации параметр `carparks` не нашел (хотя он есть в mapkit для мобильных). Подскажите, есть ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 1):

Слой парковок пока не предоставляется через API Карт.

Comment: Спасибо! А какой-либо другой метод встраивания карты с парковками на страницу возможен?

Comment: API позволяет свои кастомные слои рисовать на карте, но вам надо откуда-то найти собственные данные о парковках